# Is that possible to set background color to Card element title (react-native-elements)?

Tags: android, react-native

I need help **withreact-native-elements** Card element title background color .
I try using this code but no luck.

```
<Card titleStyle={[styles.thinkMinTextTitle , robotoWeights.light]} title='Think a minute!'></Card>
```

and this is my styles code

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ thinkMinTextTitle:{ backgroundColor:'#32cb00' }});
```

Thanks

Comment: can you try `containerStyle` instead of `titleStyle`

Comment: @AravindS He's not looking for setting up styles for the container.

Comment: @Lasitha yep. that is clear. Since `titleStyle` is bg is not working, I suggested applying for `containerStyle` to make the container transparent

Comment: @AravindS  it  try with  containerStyle but  it  not  work too.

Comment: @Lasitha Yes i need to change bg for title only